# Where to Persist Data?

Tags: php, android, mysql, hibernate, orm

I have developed an Android Application that on click of a Button in Android makes a server request.  The request is handled by a PHP script which fetch data from database and returns a String to my android application.

But in this practice my SQL server is getting hits every time a Button is clicked in my android app.  I want to reduce the Database hits by creating some persistent layer.

Where and how can a Persistent layer be created?

1. Using Hibernate in android if possible?
2. Using OrmLite to connect MySQL server instead of Sqlite.?
3. By keeping a persistent layer on PHP?
4. Using shared preferences but then I might need an alarm clock to update the data.

or if there is some other best way possible.  Thanks! :)

Comment: It's of course a course related question. Good question!

Comment: I think if you do a GET request using volley the volley library will do caching for you provided you have caching headers in your response.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to do is a REST client. Therefore there are 3 architectural best practices for realizing such a REST Android client with a persistence layer.
These have been described pretty good at the [Google IO of 2010](https://youtu.be/xHXn3Kg2IQE).